# Can unclear or deceptive company news and updates affect the stock price in the opposite direction of where the company is actually headed?

Tags: stocks, news

Inspired by my [previous question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43955/are-traders-100-responsible-for-a-stocks-price-changes), if the traders are the main cause for the price change of the stock, does that mean unclear or deceptive company news and updates can affect the stock price in the opposite direction of where the company is actually headed?

Comment: What do you mean by "actually headed"? The perception of the company's current and future financial health is, as previously discussed, the _only_ thing that determines the stock price. So if there's **enough** bad news about a company -- even if it's completely wrong -- such that **everyone** believes the company is going under, no matter what other evidence (like account statements) they see, then the company will "actually head" to zero even if it's perfectly healthy financially. There is no "true price" or "correct price" for a stock -- there is only what other people will pay you for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only in a relatively short term. False news or speculations can definitely change the stock price, sometimes even significantly. However, the stock price will eventually (in the long-term) correct itself and head to the right direction.

Comment: I'd argue that false and misleading news, if issued by the company, is definitely a signal that something is wrong at the company and will end up being priced in!